# how to store node set

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm calling a template which returns node set and i tried to store it on a variable but it returning only values not node names

```
<MaxData>
  <xsl:variable name="maxP">
    <xsl:call-template name="MaxPeaks"/>
      </xsl:variable> 
</MaxData>

  <xsl:template name="MaxPeaks">
        <DailyPeakDmds>
           <xsl:text>Test1</xsl:text>
        </DailyPeakDmds>
        <DailyPeakDmds>
           <xsl:text>Test2</xsl:text>
        </DailyPeakDmds>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Sending node set to c# code file:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="code:GetMax($maxP)"/>
```

But in c# method it giving result "Test1 Test2" but i need like:

```
<DailyPeakDmds>
   Test1
</DailyPeakDmds>
<DailyPeakDmds>
   Test2
</DailyPeakDmds>
```

when i test the variable 'maxP' it contains "Test1 Test2" values, and it doesn't contain node names any one help me how to get node set and store it.

Comment: How are you "testing" the variable?  Remember that `<xsl:value-of>` will give you the _string value_ of the fragment, which means just the concatenation of the text nodes.  If you want the structure you need to use `<xsl:copy-of>`.

Comment: yeah concatenation of nodes 'm getting now. And I'm using $maxP it giving me concatenation results, so what can i do to get node set?

Comment: And i need to do calculation of this node set in c# code file so i'm sending this node set to c# code file as code:GetMax($maxP) but there i'm getting only text nodes not node sets :(

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer my self by giving path to node set like below

```
<xsl:copy-of select="code:GetMax(msxsl:node-set($maxP)/DailyPeakDmds/*)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="code:GetMax($maxP)"/>
```

will pass the *result tree fragment* contained in the `maxP` variable to your extension function, then convert the return value of that extension function to a string and include that string value in the output.  If the function returns a node set or another result tree fragment and you want to include those nodes in your output as-is (as opposed to just the string value of the node set) then you should use `copy-of` instead of `value-of`.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="code:GetMax($maxP)"/>
```

If the function expects its *parameter* to be a node set rather than a result tree fragment then you will need to use an extension function to convert `$maxP`.  Since you mention C# I presume you're using the .NET XSLT processor, in which case you probably want [the msxsl:node-set function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256197.aspx)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="code:GetMax(msxsl:node-set($maxP))" />
```

Comment: The result $maxP contains concatenation of values like "Test1 Test2" but maxP should contain node set.

Comment: @user1805169 the `$maxP` variable contains a "result tree fragment" - if `GetMax` expects a node set you'll have to use an extension function to convert it.

Comment: Getting same tree fragment result even after replaced with your suggestion as above.